# columns missing while reading a huge csv file in jupyter nootebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

So i am trying to read a csv file by the code as below:

```
import pandas as pd
user_cols = ['id','listing_type','status','listing_class','property_type','street_address','city','state',' 'zip_4','cross_street','street_index','unit','floor','location','Latitude',
             'longitude','subway','neighborhood','price','incentives','fee_type','fee_percentage','fee_details_broker',
             'fee_details_clients','application_information','maintenance','taxes','max_financing','other_costs','beds',
             'baths','full_baths','three_quarter_baths','half_baths','total_rooms','square_feet','exterior_square_feet',
            'lot_area','lot_dimensions','date_available','date_listed','closed_on','year_built','recent_renovation',
             'lease_min','lease_max','date_added','date_edited','date_update','contact','access','keys','mls_name','mls_id',
            'courtesy_of','vow_opt_out','idx_opt_out','pet_details','notes','sync','private','listing_score','added_by_id',
            'featured_office_id','date_expires','exclusive_file_id','condition','guarantor','blast_link']

data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\dump-4.csv", low_memory=False, dtype=object, header=None, names=user_cols)
```

I am able to read the file but when i try to display the columns there are about 15-16 column names that are missing. Why is this happening and what can I do.

Comment: Are the columns missing or hidden to make the table small enough?

Comment: @MaartenFabré not sure..but i was getting key error while trying to access one of the missing columns. But now i am able to see all the columns once i removed the dtype=object & header=None. Thank you so much for such a quick response.

Answer (score 0):

So when i deleted the dtype=object and header=None..it did print all the columns. not really sure what wouldve been the correct dtype though! Thanks anyway! :)